# Dropzone.js not submitting files

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

I've tried everything and I just can't get dropzone.js to send files to the server. I feel like there must be something very fundamental that I'm not getting here.

All I'm trying to do right now is to get the files to upload automatically when the user selects them (styling doesn't matter) but it doesn't seem to be triggering my php code and I'm left to assume that it isn't submitting (the target page is the same as the page calling it).

HTML:

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        print "Files exist";
    }
?>

<ul class="submission_container">
    <li id="file_01" title="Click here to upload files">
        <div class="ledger_preview">
            <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="file-one">
                +
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
Dropzone.options.fileOne = {
    url: 'submit.php',
    paramName: 'file_01',
    method: 'POST',
    parallelUploads: 1,
    clickable: true,
    maxFilesize: 7,
    acceptedFiles: 'application/pdf',
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    dictDefaultMessage: '',
    dictFallbackMessage: '',
    dictFallbackText: '',
    dictFallbackText: '',
    dictInvalidFileType: '',
    dictFileTooBig: '',
    dictResponseError: '',
    dictCancelUpload: '',
    dictCancelUploadConfirmation: '',
    dictRemoveFile: '',
    dictMaxFilesExceeded: '',

    accept: function(file, done) {
        done();
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.submission_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.ledger_preview {
    height: 7.647em;
    width: 12em;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1em solid #A3A3A3;
}

.dropzone {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8em;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #A3A3A3;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

FSFiddle (without PHP):
http://jsfiddle.net/qo4cLeco/

Comment: Do you see any network requests in the web inspector when trying to upload? What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome - Doesn't seem to be any network requests. I'm running all of this locally over WAMP if it makes any difference

Comment: I didn't think I needed one as they don't show one in their example
http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage

Comment: dropzone isnt working for me... when i do a normal Browse and upload without dropzone.. my $_FILES gets printed.. But when i use dropzone, my $_FILES gives me error 4

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have both - action parameter in the form and url parameter in the Dropzone.

Url parameter in Dropzone [has to be specified on elements other than form (or when the form doesn't have an action attribute).](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-url)

In your JsFiddle example the post is made to /file-upload - are you sure you're waiting the uploaded files there? Or you're waiting them in submit.php?

I believe it should all work ok if you remove the one you don't need - either action parameter in the form or url parameter in DropZone configuration.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was misunderstanding the mechanics of what was happening. The files were submitting through an ajax call while I was expecting the page to reload. The code seems to work when I replace my PHP with the code needed to stick the files onto the server.